# How disable timestaps on the end of chunks in Next.js

Tags: next.js

Running next.js locally, chunks are served with timestamp parameter, for example `/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1686247679035`.

1. Is it possible to disable this additional `?ts=1686247679035`?
2. Is it also added in the production build?

Comment: I do not think this is possible, what exactly are you trying to achieve by removing the timestamp?